# How to install wxPython on Windows 7 as pre-req of Ride

Tags: wxpython, robotframework

I have wxPython3.0-win32-3.0.2.0-py27 and when I try to run it, it prompts for "Put a directory on PYTHONPATH here" I do not know why? I have Python 3.5.0 
n Robot Framework 2.9   already installed successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong version of wxPython.

From the [installation instructions](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/wiki/Installation-Instructions):

> RIDE's GUI is implemented using wxPython toolkit. **Only wxPython
>   2.8.12.1 with Unicode support is officially supported**. Possible new releases in wxPython 2.8 series ought to work fine too. wxPython 3.0
>   support is one of the priorities for future development.

Comment: wxPython 2.8.12.1 only works with Python 2 as well, so the OP needs to use Python 2 instead of 3.5